# django-admin --version syntax error in windows command prompt

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, syntax-error, python-3.4

I have installed Django latest version i.e 2.1 on my pc and also updated my currently installed python version from 3.5.rc1 to 3.7.1. But still command
'Django-admin --version' giving error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
   "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
   exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
   from django.conf import settings
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 18, in
   from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 12
   return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
```